# What does P(X=Y) mean?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let X and Y be binary random variables, with $P(X = 0) = 1/4$, $P(Y = 0) = 1/4$ and $P(X = Y) = 1/2$

I want to calculate $P(X=x,Y=y)$ (i.e. probability of x and y) and P(X=x|Y=y) for all all x and y.

As soon as I find even one of those values say P(X=0,Y=0) I can calculate everything else using conditional probability formulae.

But I don't know how to start. What does P(X=Y) mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are given $$\begin{array}{rcl}
P(X=Y)=P(X=0,Y=0)+P(X=1,Y=1)&=&\frac12\\
P(X=0)=P(X=0,Y=0)+P(X=0,Y=1)&=&\frac14\\
P(Y=0)=P(X=0,Y=0)+P(X=1,Y=0)&=&\frac14.
\end{array}
$$
Since probabilities of all possible $(X,Y)$ pairs add up to 1, you also know that
$$
P(X=0,Y=0)+P(X=0,Y=1)+P(X=1,Y=0)+P(X=1,Y=1)=1.
$$
Solving these four equations in four unknowns gives you the required answer.

Comment: I considered this, but does that mean $P(X=0,Y=0) = 1/4$?

Answer (score 1):

$P(X=Y)$ means the probability that $X$ is equal to $Y$.

Hint: there are four possible pairs $(x,y)$ to consider.